# Spanner how 'deep' is primary key character count indexed? e.g. would there be mega-hot spot if the first 2 characters are the same +1

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key, google-cloud-spanner

I'm using Spanner for the first time.

I am using a UUIDv4 for a primary key, but I'm building a table that I think from my understanding could benefit from another primary key (or maybe a secondary index is better? but i'm still learning how to use those in Spanner and my knowledge there is less, especially how to build / maintain after new or modified rows).

Because I will be in some instances selecting by WHERE primary_key AND another_primary_phone_number_key

For instance this table let's call it users would have org_id | uuid | formatted_phone_number, where all phone numbers start with +1 before getting to the mostly even distributed 1-9 3rd string character

Here is how that schema would look - shortened for the example

Would this actually distribute evenly in I believe Spanner calls them Splits? Or would it be one giant hotspot because they all start with +?

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  org_id STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
  user_uuid STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
  formatted_phone_number STRING(MAX),
  fb_uuid STRING(MAX),
  FOREIGN KEY(org_id) REFERENCES accounts(org_id),
) PRIMARY KEY(org_id, user_uuid, formatted_phone_number),
  INTERLEAVE IN PARENT accounts ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific example should (probably) be good, as the important part is to avoid having a primary key whose first **column** is not monotonically increasing or decreasing. In your example, the first column is the organization key. If this key is well distributed, for example because it is a UUID, then this should be fine.

So even if the phone number that is included as the third column of the primary key were to be monotonically increasing/decreasing, you would still be good, as it is not the first part of the key.

Furthermore: Assume that the phone number was the first column of the primary key, and they all start with `'+1'` followed by some random string, it would still be a good primary key, as the index is constructed based on the entire string. It would only be a problem if you were writing all phone numbers in alphabetical order to the table.

Comment: AWESOME! thank you ;) for google search keywords since I couldn't find an existing answer here is a comment that says thank you for the answer that the entire length of the primary key string for google spanner is indexed, not just the first character! and the strings are random order written to the database so they will be distributed randomly